# Errors laravel valet on windows

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, valet

i am trying to install laravel valet on windows via the procedure described here
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows

When I run the composer command I always get these errors

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cretueusebiu/valet-windows[v0.1.0, ..., v0.1.2] require symfony/process ^3.0 -> found symfony/process[v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - cretueusebiu/valet-windows[v0.1.3, ..., v0.1.8, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.8, 2.0.3, ..., 2.0.14] require symfony/process ~2.7|~3.0 -> found symfony/process[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.0.15, ..., 2.1.1] require symfony/process ~2.7|~3.0|~4.0 -> found symfony/process[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.1.2, ..., 2.1.5] require symfony/process ~2.7|~3.0|~4.0|~5.0 -> found symfony/process[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.28] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.2.0, ..., 2.4.1] require symfony/process ^4.0|^5.0 -> found symfony/process[v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.28] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.5.0, ..., 2.5.1] require illuminate/collections ^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/collections[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but the package is fixed to v10.21.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires cretueusebiu/valet-windows * -> satisfiable by cretueusebiu/valet-windows[v0.1.0, ..., v0.1.8, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.8, 2.0.3, ..., 2.5.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require cretueusebiu/valet-windows:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require cretueusebiu/valet-windows:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

how can i fix it?

Are there php.ini file extensions to enable?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I would assume that you are using Laravel v10 (as the error message shows). `cretueusebiu/valet-windows` hasn't seen any updates since more than a year and is not compatible with v10. As the package doesn't show any activity within the last months, I doubt that anybody cares to make it compatible.